# select an entry with specified id, and also one entry before and after with the same foreign key value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which looks like this one:

```
| id | fk_book | name |
-----------------------
| 1  | 2       | test1|
| 3  | 2       | test3|
| 6  | 3       | notes|
| 7  | 2       | test2|
```

No I want to get the entry with the id 3. select * from test where id=3 AND fk_book=1;

but is there also a way to get the item with id 1 and 7?
and I dont know the ids of the other entries

thanks

Comment: nope because 6 is not in fk_book=1

Comment: @AndreyGurinov I'm guessing he means "items with the same foreign key". Maybe the OP can clarify that.

Comment: Is there typo? FK = 2? Anyway, take a look on my answer, I think it what you need

Comment: Do you know the FK you are looking for in advance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
select * from test where id=3 AND fk_book = 2
union all 
select * from test where id < 3 AND fk_book = 2 order by id desc limit 1
union all 
select * from test where id > 3 AND fk_book = 2 order by id asc limit 1
```

Comment: +1 this is most likely what the OP refers to, rather than providing all the id's himself/herself.

Comment: This would return items 3, 1 and 6 in that order which is not what the OP asked for. See my edit to the question's title following the OP's comment.

Comment: @liquorvicar indeed `AND fk_book = 2` should be added to every where clause.

Comment: thanks a lot! my teacher wasn't able to help me....

Comment: @liquorvicar As for order of the output, it could be fixed by adding outer SELECT with ORDER BY, or by ordering sub-SELECTs. Not a point at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try following sql query:

```
select * from test where id in(1,3,7);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to provide just the id 3 and get also the previous and the next record (regardless of their ids).

Comment: @Bazzz, i had to wait for op to edit the question =)